# Porque no aparece completo? en el jframe no aparezca el minimizar, el maximizar y la x

Tags: java-swing, jframe

He visto muchos videos pero ni uno soluciona esto:

[image: Preview JFrame vacío]

y no me aparece completo. ¿Alguien que le pase o le pas´ lo mismo? ¿Y cómo lo solucionó para que me ayude? Porque si agrando más ya ni se ve el minimizar.

```
public class FormNuevo extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public FormNuevo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 681, 357);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FormNuevo frame = new FormNuevo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Italo, bienvenido al sitio. Da la sensación de que eso que has capturado es un preview del JFrame que hace NetBeans. ¿Cuándo lo ejecutas no te salen esos botones en la ventana? ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir tu código como texto formateado?

Comment: hola, es Eclipse IDE:

Comment: import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
public class FormNuevo extends JFrame {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private JPanel contentPane;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     FormNuevo frame = new FormNuevo();
     frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }

Comment: public FormNuevo() {
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setBounds(100, 100, 681, 357);
  contentPane = new JPanel();
  contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
  setContentPane(contentPane);
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

He probado el código que has incluido en los comentarios y no he sido capaz de reproducir el error que indicas. Los botones aparecen correctamente cuando ejecutas el método main, como puede apreciarse en la imagen de abajo.

[image: Vista JFrame]

Es decir, no es un problema de tu código, puede ser un problema del plug-in de Eclipse que muestra el preview. Prueba a actualizar la versión de Eclipse o utiliza un IDE o un plug-in distinto.

Por otro lado, IntelliJ me ha sugerido un par de mejoras respecto a tu código original

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FormNuevo extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public FormNuevo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 681, 357);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                FormNuevo frame = new FormNuevo();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

La primera es que no necesitas indicar explícitamente que la constante EXIT_ON_CLOSE se importa de la clase JFrame.

La segunda es que desde Java 8 puedes sustituir los interfaces funcionales, aquellas que solo tienen un método abstracto que debe sobreescribirse como Runnable, por una expresión lambda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        try {
            FormNuevo frame = new FormNuevo();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Y que plug-in me recomiendas..? tengo ésta version que sale del cmd:
java -version
java version "21" 2023-09-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21+35-LTS-2513)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-LTS-2513, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @Italo Hace años que no trabajo con Eclipse, no sabría recomendarte un plug-in. Y lo que me indicas es la versión de java, no el plug-in que permite previsualizar los elementos de la librería Swing. De todas formas, no entiendo bien tu preocupación, cuándo ejecutas tu método main, ¿no te salen esos botones de cierre, minimizar y maximizar? Un cosa es el preview que te ofrece el IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans) y otra cosa es cómo se ejecuta tu programa. Puede haber ligeras diferencias entre lo primero y lo segundo.